# Android - compress bitmap before saving it to SDCARD in activity for result

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, compression, android-camera

I've been busting my head on this, and not so sure what to do. What I am trying to do is: Take a picture, compress it to png (keeping the original dimensions), and then save it to sdCard. The reason why I need to do this is because I have to recompress it again, then Base64 encode it so i can send it to a server. The problem is 1. the file is too big  2. i am running out of memory and 3. not sure if I am doing this correctly.

Thanks for your help

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View button) {
    switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.cameraButton:
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/test.png")));
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            break;
        case R.id.galleryButton:
            sendToDatabase();
            break;
    }
}

// Camera on activity for result - save it as a bmp and place in imageview
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        // do something
    }

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "result ok");

        picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test.png");

        // Create string to place it in sd card
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        //create output stream
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        //create file
        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "test.png");
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, outputStream);
            //picture.recycle();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR");
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);
    }
}

public void sendToDatabase() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    //get the picture from location
    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test.png");

    // CONVERT:
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Boolean didItWork = picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, outStream);
    picture.recycle();
    if (didItWork = true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "compression worked");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "AFTER. Height: " + picture.getHeight() + " Width: "
        + picture.getWidth());
    final byte[] ba = outStream.toByteArray();
    try {
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that Bitmap.compress(..) quality setting does not have effect on PNG compression. If you're into reducing file size, your options are either lossy JPG or dropping image size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you do picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, outStream); the compression wont work as PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting. So the parameter 50 wont work in this case. So i suggest you to change CompressFormat.PNG to CompressFormat.JPEG.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up compressing it to JPEG.